# SQL Query data with count grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in one database table (Columns A to E). I need a query to show the same columns (A to E), adding two extra columns.

In Excel I used the following formula's to do this, but I'm not able to do it with a query (SQL Server):

```
=SI(CONTAR.SI(C$2:C2;C2)=1;1;0)
=(CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(C$2:C2;C2;$D$2:D2;D2)=1)*1

A ----- B ----- C ----- D ----- E ----- COUNT (DISTINCT C) ----- COUNT (DISTINCT C&D)
1 ----- 26 -- 4650 ---- 1 ---- 11 ----- 1 ---------------------------------- 1
1 ----- 26 -- 4650 ---- 1 ---- 22 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 0
1 ----- 26 -- 4650 ---- 9 ---- 11 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 1
1 ----- 26 -- 4650 ---- 9 ---- 22 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 0
1 ----- 26 -- 50934 --- 1 ---- 11 ----- 1 ---------------------------------- 1
1 ----- 26 -- 50934 --- 1 ---- 22 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 0
1 ----- 26 -- 50934 --- 1 ---- 40 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 0
1 ----- 26 -- 51097 --- 3 ---- 40 ----- 1 ---------------------------------- 1
1 ----- 26 -- 51097 --- 3 ---- 41 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 0
1 ----- 26 -- 51097 --- 4 ---- 40 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 1
1 ----- 26 -- 51097 --- 4 ---- 41 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 0
3 ----- 34 -- 50099 --- 1 ---- 40 ----- 1 ---------------------------------- 1
3 ----- 34 -- 50099 --- 1 ---- 41 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 0
3 ----- 34 -- 50099 --- 1 ---- 42 ----- 0 ---------------------------------- 0
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help others to help you if under your example, you tell us what you've tried in the way of SQL and what results you got (even if they're just errors - paste the errors).  You're likely to get more help than simply asking for code to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want flags to indicate the first group for `c` and for `c` and `d`.  Assuming that you have some column that specifies the ordering, you can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by c order by id) = 1
             then 1 else 0 end),
       (case when row_number() over (partition by c, d order by id) = 1
             then 1 else 0 end)
from table t;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no first row in the groups, unless another column specifies the ordering.  Typically, tables have `identity` columns and/or creation dates with this type of information.

Comment: it's there a way to do the same but, I want to count 1 when partition A, B, C and where E = 41 ?

Comment: @Sebastián . . . New question should be asked as questions, not in comments.